# long term session storage (php shopping cart)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session

this is more of a 'can you point me in the right direction' type of question.

Basically I would like to offer customers a way to 'save' their shopping cart, perhaps to view later with a relative (it's a 'photo basket' for a photographers clients).

When my 'photo basket' is used, it creates a single basket `array` that is then filled with item `arrays`.

My idea was --- create a table for each user and then `implode` each array in the `$_SESSION['basket']` to a `string` and then add this string to a row in the DB. When the user logs back in, their saved basket can then be exploded from the database to form a new basket...

That's my chain of thought (not started this section yet). Just wondered if anyone could spot any obvious flaws and errors I might encounter.

Thanks for any input.

Shane

Comment: I was thinking about doing mine this way as well. The problem you have to think about is when will the row be updated? Is it something the user decides on (i.e. a save button) or should it do it per page. Also, make sure you have some kind of expiration on it so that it will eventually go away.

Comment: You may wish to save the baskets directly to a database table instead of serializing an array from session (easier to work with, plus you don't have to worry about save/restore, as it's already in persistent storage).

Comment: Good point. My idea was to ignore the whole `save to database` idea until the user actually clicks `save to view later`, then I's go ahead and save the data. Upon logging back in, the user will then be able to start from scratch or choose to 'load your last basket'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't create a table for each user. You can create a single table with a userid and datavalue columns, and save all users' baskets in the one table. Nor do you want to implode... use serialize on the $_SESSION['basket'] before storing it on the database, and unserialize when reading it back from the database

Comment: Sound advice. Thanks, not sure why I was thinking of a new table for each user... *insert generic tired-related excuse here*  :)  Thanks for the heads-up on `serialize`, I've not used that one yet...

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that `serialize` will take an array and automatically turn it into a string that I can insert into a DB row?

Comment: Correct, serialize will take any PHP datatype (not just arrays) and convert it into a text format that can be stored in a database, while unserialize will recreate the original datatype from that string. The only exception is the resource datatype, which cannot be serialized, and resource attributes in objects.

Comment: Fantastic. The creators of PHP seem to have gone to great lengths to make this language easy-to-use. :) No wonder it's become so popular.

Comment: php's serialize() is somewhat analogous to Javascript's json, if that helps any. They both take internal data structures and turn them into plaintext string that can be easily passed around.

Comment: AH! While we're talking javascipt, what's the most effective way to pass a php array to javascript?

Answer (score 1):

as mention before, don't create table, create a row. There are few php carts that do that (cs-cart).
However, delete old baskets from the table after a while...